# WPF How do I reference x:Name elements in code behind of a base view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance

I have several views that could benefit from a base class. Each derived view has this XAML.

```
        <oxy:PlotView x:Name="Plot" Model="{Binding PlotModel}" Grid.Column="2" Loaded="Plot_OnLoaded" Unloaded="Plot_UnLoaded" MinHeight="{Binding MinimumPlotHeight}">
```

I want this code to be in the base class.

```
    protected void Plot_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var axis in Plot.ActualModel.Axes)
        {
            if (axis.Position != AxisPosition.Bottom)
                continue;
        
            XAxis = axis;
            break;
        }
        
        if (XAxis != null)
            XAxis.AxisChanged += OnAxisChanged;
    }
```

As you see it references Plot, which the base class has no knowledge of. I tried adding a property to the base class, to let it know what Plot is.

```
public PlotView Plot { get; set; }
```

This allows the everything to compile and run, but Plot is just null, which I guess is no surprise. How can I let the base class know about this name in the derived XAML?

Comment: The PlotView is passed via the `sender` argument. Declare a local variable: `var plot = (PlotView)sender;`

Comment: Thanks. If you post this, I will select it as the answer.

Comment: This is not a good design decision. Why would the base class not know that it has a PlotView when it needs to handle it? You should create a baseclass that also comes with a PlotView in its ControlTemplate. Or override the OnApplyTemplate to search for the PlotView. The point is you need the instance before you can handle any events bevcause you must register the event handlers first. So, the Plot property should be a private property of the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a variation of Clemens' and BionicCode's suggestions. I defined this property:

```
public PlotView Plot { get; private set; }
```

and modified the onloaded handler.

```
    protected void Plot_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Plot = sender as PlotView;
        foreach (var axis in Plot.ActualModel.Axes)
        {
            if (axis.Position != AxisPosition.Bottom)
                continue;
        
            XAxis = axis;
            break;
        }
        
        if (XAxis != null)
            XAxis.AxisChanged += OnAxisChanged;
    }
```

I made Plot a public property because I am also using it in the base class here.

```
    protected void OnAxisChanged(object sender, AxisChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if true then stop any recursion
        if (IsInternalChange)
            return;

        var xMin = XAxis.ActualMinimum;
        var xMax = XAxis.ActualMaximum;

        foreach (SyncrhonisedTrackView track in _parentView.TrackList)
        {
            if (track == this)
                continue;

            track.IsInternalChange = true;

            // do not use zoom to set axis, it can lead to recursion
            track.XAxis.AbsoluteMinimum = xMin;
            track.XAxis.AbsoluteMaximum = xMax;
            track.Plot.InvalidatePlot(false);
            track.IsInternalChange = false;
        }
    }
```

Hopefully that will satisfy any design issues.